# How to get Kendo Grid Row with one of its column's unique value

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to find and get kendo grid row when a specific column value match.
Following is my Kendo grid rendering where it is bound to a data table. This data table has a unique identifier column named "Id". I want to retrieve the grid row by comparing the Id column value.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.lstDataTables[i].ADataTable)                                                    
    .Name(Model.lstDataTables[i].PWRId + "-Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        foreach (System.Data.DataColumn column in Model.lstDataTables[i].ADataTable.Columns)                  {
            columns.Bound(column.DataType, column.ColumnName);
        }
    })
    .Scrollable()
)
```

Following is my jquery code where I am trying to get the row, but unsuccessful.

```
var gridRow = $(gridName).data("kendoGrid").tbody.find("tr[Id='" + 2 + "']");
```

Following are the screen shots of grid and DOM Explorer
[image: Grid Screen Shot]

[image: DOM Explorer]

Could anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DOM screenshot you've posted in your question is for the column headers. You should define your model's id in your grid's data source, like this:

```
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Model(model => model.Id(m => m.Id))
```

Then, you can get a row with Id = 2 like this (assuming your grid name is "grid"):

```
var dataItem = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.get(2);
var row = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").tbody
              .find("tr[data-uid='" + dataItem.uid + "']");
```

Comment: Hi Ataravati, my data source is the data table that i have already supplied in the grid definition i-e. @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.lstPageAndWidgetsData[i].PageWidgetData). Do you mean that I have to change the grid definition by supplying the data source rather passing my data table directly to the grid ?

Comment: I don't think you have to do that. Why don't you try it?

Comment: I have tried that but it don't like when I do dataSource.Model and complain about Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.DataSourceBuilder<System.Data.DataRowView> doesn't cotain a definition for 'Model'

Comment: What do you mean you don't like it?

Comment: I have edited my above comment and added the error. I didn't me I don't like. I just meant to say it don't allow me to access model from dataSource.

Comment: No, try it without even adding that datasource part to your grid. Just try the jquery code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94443/discussion-between-learning-curve-and-ataravati).